# Pass parameters to javascript using wp_localize_script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have read a half-dozen examples of how to pass parameters to javascript and they all describe the process in a very similar manner but don't speak to one event: how does the javascript code actually get called? I have seen several examples where the code is tested in $document.ready, but can't get them to work.

Here is my php code:

```
$base_id = 'id_'.wp_create_nonce("postlister");
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parms = array(
    'url'       => $url,
    'action'    => $action,
    'base_id'   => base_id );
wp_localize_script(self::slug.'-postlister', 'postlister_parms', $parms);
```

And my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (postlister_parms) {
    if (postlister_parms !== undefined) {
        var parms = postlister_parms;
        $.diagnostic('postlister loaded');
    }
});
```

When the page loads, there is a div generated were my code writes some additional html:

```
    echo '<div id="'.$base_id.'"></div>';
```

produces:

```
<div id="id_c8aca14643"></div>
```

The footer contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mkpusa.org/nw/wp-content/plugins/rhj4-postlister/js/postlister.js?ver=3.9.2"></script>
```

When the jQuery code executes, postlister_parms is a function:

```
postlister_parms: function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
```

But postlister_parms.url, .action and .base_id are all undefined.

Please help me spot what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting code should look something like this:

```
var postlister_parms = {"url":"the_url","action":"the_action","base_id":"the_baseid"};
```

Make sure that the script with the handle `self::slug.'-postlister'` is enqueued before you call `wp_localize_script`

Comment: I have walked into the wp_localize_script code and here is what is generated: "var postlister_parms = {"url":"localhost\/mkpusa.org\/nw\/postlister-test\/","action":"categories","base_id":"base_id"};"

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the Notes section of the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)  The call to wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script should be in a wp_enqueue_scripts action and the script should be enqueued before it is localized.  That being true, it should work

Comment: The script is registered and queued before it is called. The is a shortcode which fires the php code and the PHP code above is from the function registered with add_shortcode. It is getting called properly.

Comment: Do you mean you localize the script in the actual shortcode code?  That won't work.  As I said "The call to wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script should be in a wp_enqueue_scripts action" which means you have to register them before the wp_enqueue_scrips action is run (i.e. before the html head is created)  Shortcodes run too late.  You could output your own script block which creates such an object, as long as you are very careful not to use it before it is created.